# ionic2 - launch num pad keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ionic2

Is there a way to launch num pad keyboard when click on `input` field in `ionic2`? I cannot find any reference other than the one from the market place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-input type="number" ></ion-input>
```

Comment: @sooon are you testing this using emulator? Num keyboard shouldn't appear on the browser but works on the device. If not, try something like this `<ion-input type="tel" ></ion-input>` .

Comment: I am testing it via emulator and I get normal keyboard. Have not test with actual device yet though.